# Easylogging++ how to configure with single macro?

Tags: c++, logging, macros, easylogging++

I would like to create a simple macro that does what `_INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP` does, but that accepts a configuration string like this one:

```
"*GLOBAL:\nFILENAME = my_app.log\nFORMAT = %datetime{%Y.%M.%d-%H.%m.%s.%g}, %level, %msg\n*INFO:\n ENABLED=false"
```

The macro would then replace:

```
_INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP
```

by

```
INITIALIZE_ELPP_WITH_CONFIG("myconfigstring")
```

Anyone has an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a function like this one :

```
void initializeLogs(const char* config_string)
{
    _INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP
   easyloggingpp::Configurations c;
   c.setToDefault();
   c.parseFromText(config_string);
   easyloggingpp::Loggers::reconfigureAllLoggers(confFromFile);
}
```

then call :

```
initializeLogs("*GLOBAL:\nFILENAME = my_app.log\nFORMAT = %datetime{%Y.%M.%d-%H.%m.%s.%g}, %level, %msg\n*INFO:\n ENABLED=false");
```

Comment: That won't work. The macro _INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP declares variables that need to static for the logger to work since it's header- only library.

Comment: @Darien Just put the _INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP outside of the function then. You still have the initializaton done in separate function and achieve much of what you were after.